# Eclipse installing IBM Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to install an IBM plugin into Eclipse. I have downloaded the web installer and have followed all the steps with no issues apart from the last one.

When it asks to be pointed to the Eclipse IDE it says that the version is not supported and doesnt match the 1.7 requirements.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled eclipse several times ensuring that the version is correct (4.2.2), I have also manually added the 1.7 JDK. Along with these two approaches I have also changed the enviroment variables on my laptop to make sure that they also point to 1.7 versions (both PATH and JAVA_HOME).

I cant think of any other reasons as to way I am still getting an error. Can anyone else think of a possible reasoning why this isnt working or have I left out a process?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. My problem was that when I installed Eclipse I was running Java 1.8 and this is what the Eclipse VM was set to. To fix the issue I edited the Eclipse ini file to point to the correct 1.7 VM.